# Cached QSqlQueryModel to mimic OnManualSubmit

Tags: c++, qt, qtsql

I would like to implement a feature like the EditStrategy available on the QSqlTableModel but on a QSqlQueryModel because I have complex queries.

I have already created my subclass of QSqlQueryModel implementing the `setData()` following the documentation and various examples. However I would like have a feature like the `OnManualSubmit` strategy available on the QSqlTableModel class.

Any idea how to implement this caching? I also need to have the cached changes available in other view.

Comment: What if you take a look at how it's implemented for `QSqlTableModel`?

Comment: I tried but I don't manage to have a good understanding of it. I think I am too new to QT I guess. I was expected some guidelines to start, but I can also spend more time on the sources